# How to setup routing for UDP in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, udp, amazon-vpc

I'm new to AWS and I'm wondering if any one could provide a guild/link on how to go about setting up, what I'm guessing is VPC, so that I can send UDP packets to and from my instance via my public IP.

For example I'm trying right now on my local computer to do something like "netcat -u ec2PublicIP 13000" and then on the ec2 instance see the packets with "nc -l 13000". The only thing I've done so far is set my security group to allow all inbound/outbound traffic. I just don't know what else I need to do to get the UDP data flowing between the amazon public IP and the private IP on my instance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm so confused with the rules I have set I can ping the public IP and see it come through with tcpdump -i eth0 icmp, but I can't see anything on UDP?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ingress rule that matches your desired traffic to a Security Group and apply that SG to your instance.

Comment: Thats why I'm confused, I thought the setup seemed correct but I still can't pass & view traffic via UDP from my local computer to the ec2 instance

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your wording. See my edits.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the ingress rule, if I already had rules to allow all inbound/outbound isn't that enough? Where in the Security Group would I add that exception as I don't currently see it? Thanks